# Related a child table to parent table which already has a foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a relation 1 hotel has N room.

**Hotel**

```
Id (PK) identity

Name (UniqueKey)
```

**Room**

```
Id (PK) identity

Number 

Name (UniqueKey)

HotelId (FK)
```

Now a Room can be a "Special guest room". And there exist only ONE of this room per Hotel.

How can I assign that relation with my existing relation?

Comment: you can use one another entity called Room Type AC, NonAC, Guest etc...

Comment: Since your hotelid is foreign key there 1 to many relation between hotel,  one way to enforce the constraints would be to have a constraint or unique key of hotelid and name in room table. Another way would be to check when adding a room that same room doesnt exist when adding the room for hotel

Comment: Just a suggestion to have mapping table between room and hotel, your room can have various attributea leading to redundancy

Comment: Could I not put a new column on Hotel.SpecialGuestRoom (nvarchar) OR a new column on Room.IsSpecialGuestRoom (bool)?

Comment: That should go with your room table if its different attribute all together, doesnt make any sense to have it in hotel table

Comment: Better way would be to have special guest as room type and map it to the hotel

Comment: Now why I say mapping table is imagine room type, room category and other details being replicated with each room mapping. You can get rid of it using mapping table, but that would depend on attributes you have and level of normalization you want to support

Comment: there is no room type. because special guest room exist only for ONE room. There will be no other types. And the special guest room is a common room.

Comment: Just like your case we have xml room with 1-1 relation to hotel, for that we have created xml as room which is allocated to hotel when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an extra column (col) on the table(Room) and use a unique index

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UIX ON ROOM (col) where col = 1
```

Comment: I fear that this would permit only ONE special guest room among all the hotels

Answer (score 0):

You should add an extra column SpecialGuestRoomHotelID allowing NULL values on table Room and add a unique index on that column; I would also suggest to use it as FK

```
ALTER TABLE Room ADD [SpecialGuestRoomHotelID] int NULL
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Room_SpecialGuestRoomHotelID ON ROOM (SpecialGuestRoomHotelID)
ALTER TABLE [Room] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Room_Hotel_SpecialGuest] FOREIGN KEY([SpecialGuestRoomHotelID]) REFERENCES Hotel ([Id])
```

EDIT
The procedure mentioned in the comment should be something like:

```
INSERT INTO Rooms (..., SpecialGuestRoomHotelID) VALUES(..., NULL)
-- Check for errors and get the newly inserted @RoomId
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Rooms WHERE SpecialGuestRoomHotelID IS NOT NULL AND HotelId = @HotelId)
    UPDATE Rooms SET SpecialGuestRoomHotelID = @HotelId WHERE Id = @RoomId
```

Comment: I am not sure wether you understood me. Why not add a column SpecialRoomId (Default Room) to the Hotel table? Because every Hotel MUST have a Room as Default Room set. What do you think?

Comment: Why you make it nullable? There must be a default room for every hotel.

Comment: In any case it is just matter of adding a little of logic in the procedure that adds new rooms, in such a way if there is no rooms for the owning hotel the one going to be inserted will be the also the special guest one; you should also have a prociedure to change the special guest room. An alternative that I would avoid is to have triggers to control the special guest rooms

Comment: No idea why you introduce stored procedure/triggers here, I did not mention them. I just ask about the sql structure not how to access the data.

Comment: Sorry for beign OT, i was just trying to explain how the structure i suggested would have worked